# Webview, stylesheet relative path int url

Tags: android, webview

```
  <base href="http://www.myurl.com/">
        <link href="templates/default/css/mycss.css?1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am trying to load an url with the andrid webview. The page is loaded but no the css. There is a way (for the relative path). is There  a way to load the page directly with the css without caching and open it with [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    Description = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Description.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    Description.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Description.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //PodcastDescription.setTextSize(20.f);
    //PodcastDescription.setTypeface(tf);

    Bundle mybundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Integer NewsNumber = mybundle.getInt("number");


    String CurrentDescription = Entertainment.Description[NewsNumber];




    Description.loadDataWithBaseURL (null, "<html><head><style>@font-face{font-family:'MeeraRegular'; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Meera.ttf');}body{font-family:'MeeraRegular'; font-size:20px; } </style></head><body>"+CurrentDescription+"</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8",
    null);
```

Comment: I need to cache the whole page in order to get CurrentDescription. I want to avoid it